# ImageIO Can't read input file (Kotlin)

Tags: java, kotlin, discord

Hi i using kotlin to make a discord bot, I have a PNG called `sam.png`
but i try to insert and get this error:

> [23:18:38] [Fatal] [JDA]: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input
>   file!

```
override fun run(ev: MessageReceivedEvent) {
    var selaSam: Image = ImageIO.read(File("/sam.png"))
    var image = LikeUtils.downloadImage(LikeUtils.getUserHandle(ev).getEffectiveAvatarUrl())

    image.graphics.drawImage(selaSam, 200, 200, null)

    LikeUtils.sendFile(image, "/resources/sam.png", null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The path `/sam.png` means that the file is available in the root path (not the workiing path of your project but the root path of your system). I doubt that this is the case.

I guess you want that path: `./sam.png`.
Would be better to check if the file exists with

```
override fun run(ev: MessageReceivedEvent) {
    val imagePath = "/sam.png"
    val image = File(imagePath)
    if (!image.exists()) throw RuntimeException("Image $imagePath not found")
    if (image.isDirectory) throw RuntimeException("Image $imagePath is a directory")

    var selaSam: Image = ImageIO.read(image)
    var image = LikeUtils.downloadImage(LikeUtils.getUserHandle(ev).getEffectiveAvatarUrl())

    image.graphics.drawImage(selaSam, 200, 200, null)

    LikeUtils.sendFile(image, "/resources/sam.png", null)
}
```

Comment: It still gives error, I put it in the resources folder, what would path be like?

Comment: Is it still the same error, or to you now get the `RuntimeException` we throw because the image doesn't exists?

Comment: RuntimeException

Comment: If the file is stored in your project's home, just remove the heading `/`. To know where you are, you can always print out `println(File(".").absolutePath)`